# Node.js - Google Calendar API showing error "Missing end time" when inserting an event

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

I am using [Google Calendar library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-calendar) for Node.js to get calendar ID and events list from API. This is working as expected. But when I'm trying to insert or modify an event, I'm facing the common(!) error message "Missing end time".

I am trying to send a POST request using [Request - Simplified HTTP client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and not using Google Library or other package.

Here's my code snippet:

```
const request = require('request');

// Update Event Title
function insertEventIntoCalendar(calendarId,accessToken){

  let endDateTime = {
        dateTime: '2018-07-03T10:25:00.000-07:00',//end,
        timeZone: 'Asia/Dhaka'
    },
    startDateTime = {
        dateTime: '2018-07-03T10:00:00.000-07:00', //start,
        timeZone: 'Asia/Dhaka'
    },
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?access_token="+accessToken,
    options = {
        data: {
            end: endDateTime,
            start: startDateTime,
            summery: 'ARG will win',
            location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
            attendees: [],
            reminders: {
                useDefault: true,
            }
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        calendarId: 'primary'
    }

  request.post(url, options, function (err, res, body) {
     console.log('err =>', err);
     console.log('body =>', body);
  })
}
```

And here is my console.log message:

```
err => null
body => {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Missing end time."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Missing end time."
 }
}
```

**Note:** I've followed all questions and answers related to Google Calendar API and Node.js and still facing the same error. And I've not found any answers where Google Library is not used.

Please share your thoughts if you tried this way, otherwise you can suggest me a better way where I don't need any **Config** file to get or modify Google Calendar info.

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to format things correctly if you used googles client library [google-apis-nodejs-clinet](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples) or  [calendar quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs)

Comment: You made a typo in the `summary` field. You wrote `summery` instead

Comment: @DalmTo As I mentioned earlier in Note, both **Google Client Library** and **Calendar Quickstart** is using credentials.json file to get TOKEN_PATH. But I don't want to use this file in my server. Because in this process I have to generate a file for all of my users, which is probably not suitable for my project.

Comment: Solved the typo as @Jspdown said and still it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in declaring the **options** variable. The documentation of [Request - Simplified HTTP client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is saying the json data of Request body should be named as 'json'. So the **options** variable should be,

```
options = {
        url: url
        json: {
            end: endDateTime,
            start: startDateTime,
            summery: 'ARG will win',
            location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
            attendees: [],
            reminders: {
                useDefault: true,
            }
        }
    }
```

and to send the POST request, the code should be:

```
request.post(options,function (err, res, body) {
        console.log('err =>', err);
        // console.log("res =>", res);
        console.log("body =>", body);
    })
```

I tried this way and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

bonnopc answer solved it for me. For the people getting here searching for node js + Google Calendar API error, this also works there:

```
  auth.getClient().then(a => {
  calendar.events.patch({
    json: {
      summary: "bablabbla",
      start: JSON.stringify(new Date()),
      end: JSON.stringify(new Date())
    },
    auth: a,
    calendarId: GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID,
    eventId: changedEvent.id
})
})
```